# How to launch default browser from bash script

Tags: bash, default-browser

How do I launch the default Web browser from within a script? In the below script, the browser opens when the script is successfully run as an executable shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $1
php -S 127.0.0.1:5000
for f in *.html; do cp -- "$f" "${f%.html}.php"; done
x-www-browser http://127.0.0.1:5000/index.php
```

However, in this  longer version with Kdialog UI, everything executes correctly (the files are created and the server starts in the chosen directory) except for the launching of the browser

```
#!/bin/bash
`kdialog --yesno "HTML Files created, make PHP?"`
    if [ $? = 1 ]; then
    `kdialog --sorry "No PHP files created"`
    exit 1 
    fi;
    if [ $? = 0 ]; then
    `kdialog --warningcontinuecancel "Select HTML directory"`
        if [ $? = 0 ]; then
        cd `kdialog --getexistingdirectory`
        #exit 1
        else
        `kdialog --warningyesno "You didn't select a directory. \
        <br>Yes to choose, No to cancel."`
        if [ $? = 0 ]; then
        cd `kdialog --getexistingdirectory`
        exit 1
        fi;
        fi;
    fi;
        if [ $? = 0 ]; then
PORTNO=`kdialog --title "Port Number" --inputbox "Port: (Eg 7000)"`
        fi;
         if [ $? = 1 ]; then
         `kdialog --warningyesno "You didn't enter a port. <br>Yes to coose, No to cancel."`
         if [ $? = 0 ]; then
         PORTNO=`kdialog --title "Port Number" --inputbox "Port: (Eg 7000)"`
         fi;
         fi;
         if [ $? = 0 ]; then
COPYORNEW=`kdialog --radiolist "Copy HTML or make new files?:" 1 "Copy \
HTML files" off 2 "Rename HTML files" off`
         else
         exit 1
        fi;
    if [ "$COPYORNEW" = 1 ]; then
    php -S 127.0.0.1:$PORTNO
    for f in *.html; do cp -- "$f" "${f%.html}.php"; done
    #x-www-browser http://127.0.0.1:$PORTNO
    exit 1
    elif [ "$COPYORNEW" = 2 ]; then
    php -S 127.0.0.1:$PORTNO
    for f in *.html; do mv -- "$f" "${f%.html}.php"; done
    #x-www-browser http://127.0.0.1:$PORTNO
    exit 1
    fi;
URL="http://127.0.0.1:$PORTNO"; xdg-open $URL || sensible-browser $URL || x-www-browser $URL || gnome-open $URL
```

In both the short- and long-form versions, the command to open the browser is the last.

Comment: Are you sure you want to `exit 1` from the script after the copy commands? I haven't followed the logic through completely, but it looks like the script will never reach the last line

Comment: can you try xdg-open "$URL" ?

Comment: That's the first option in the list @jpbrain. I tried with the quotation marks as you have it but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Hi @MarkLee. I tried the last line in ashell and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the last line in shell and it worked. Meaning. gave a value to PORTNO and the executed the last line.

```
#!/bin/bash
PORTNO=5000
URL="http://127.0.0.1:$PORTNO"; xdg-open $URL || sensible-browser $URL || x-www-browser $URL || gnome-open $URL
```

it is working on my system (desktop 20.04.2)
is the logic ok? seems that @steeldriver has a point there.

regards.

Comment: I had already tried with removing the exits, with no success.